# Workflow update list item 'write created date in date field' does not apply to items within folders

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, folder, updatelistitems

I have a document library that receives email and splits email and attachment grouping them with a folder (all by design in 2013 version).

I have created a very simple workflow (SP designer) that copy pastes the created date into another date/time field.

The workflow works at top level (on folders) but not on sub-level (email file and attachment file within the folder).

Any idea what I should do to apply it to the inside files too?

The default view is the one with folders. Would it be enough to set as default view, the one without folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was something to activate on the server, here is the reference

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4607.sharepoint-2010-workflows-on-incoming-emails-in-sharepoint-documents-library.aspx

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn declarativeworkflowautostartonemailenabled -pv true
```